# How to start column of waterfall chart from zero

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a waterfall chart working, but I need that penultimate column start at zero.

I think I need to create a dummy point that hide and set Axis.min on the second point y position, but I can't put this working.

[image]

```
chart: {
  type: 'waterfall'
},
title: {
  text: ''
},
exporting: {
  enabled: false
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
//colors: ['#DADBDF', '#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#ED4D5F','#D7EAFD','#D7EAFD','#D7EAFD' ],
xAxis: {
  lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
  lineWidth: 0,
  gridLineColor: '#DADBDF',
  categories: [],
},
yAxis: {
  lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
  lineWidth: 0,
  gridLineColor: '#DADBDF',
  plotBands: [{
    color: '#000000', 
    from: 0, 
    to: 0 
  }],
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
},
legend: {
  enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    },
    colorByPoint: true,
    pointWidth: 150
  },
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.y}'
    },
    turboThreshold: 0,
    label: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [],
  showInLegend: false,
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `waterfall` series with defined `x` values:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'waterfall'
    },
    ...,
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            grouping: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [...]
    }, {
        data: [{
            y: 569000,
            x: 5
        }, {
            y: 1569000,
            x: 6
        }]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qc07y5kf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.waterfall.data

Comment: Thanks for reply. But in this case, we are adding two columns to the end. Is there any chance to add this columns before the last?

Comment: I change the x value, but nothing happens on position to the next column.

Comment: Before the last? Do you mean something like: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5dvnq2xb/ ?

Comment: Thanks again for you reply. It's more like that. https://jsfiddle.net/1mjz2gxf/1/ But the variable costs, needs to start on zero

Comment: It's possible to do that? Mr @ppotaczeck ?

Comment: So you need to edit the last `y` value from the first series. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1rzhu6d2/

Comment: Thanks again. But the y value came from database. I just need that column start on zero. 
As you said, this value would always have to be a calculation to give zero.

https://jsfiddle.net/9dhop74f/

In this example, I need that Variable costs start on zero.

Comment: Ok, so you can modify the column svg element. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nq3kwru2/